# What is the proper way of overriding a generic method?

Tags: java, generics

```
public abstract class Abc<T> {
    public abstract void f1(T a);  
}

abstract class Def<T> extends Abc {

    @Override
    public void f1(T a) {
        System.out.print("f");
    }

}
```

This gives the following error:
" method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your class definition needs to indicate that you're extending the parent class generically.

```
abstract class Def<T> extends Abc<T>
```

Otherwise, the compiler more or less assumes that you're extending `Abc<object>`, so the method signature that includes a `T` parameter doesn't match the one from the parent class (since it's using a different `T` parameter).